# Why my assert has different value?

Tags: python, unittesting, vyper

I am following [Vyper unittestting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8-GeDWpUeVI&list=PLFPZ8ai7J-iQMTChqif-XVP8DYABA4rx1&index=7&ab_channel=MoralisWeb3)

Here is my contract and unit test

```
# @version ^0.3.0

#Contract Guess Number
#Contract should support multiple guess the number games.
#Creator of games should rish 10 ETH to start a new game.
#A secret number is established during game creation
#The secret number should be between 0-100.
#The game creator cannot play in the games he created.
#Each guess of the number in a game will cost 1 ETH.
#Each game should allow only 10 gusses, once the tenth guess is made
#the contract will expire and the funds will go to the game creator.
#Whoever makes the right guess will win the balance of the game.
#Once the right guess is made a game should not allow people to play.
#Once a game makesa payment 1% of the amount will go to the contract creator as a fee.

struct game:
    game_owner: address
    secret_number: uint256
    game_balance: uint256
    guess_count: uint256
    is_active: bool

curr_id: uint256
game_index: HashMap[uint256, game]
contract_owner: address

@external
def __init__():
    self.contract_owner = msg.sender
    self.curr_id = 0

@external
@payable
def create_game(_secret_number: uint256) -> uint256:
    assert msg.value == 10*10**18, "You must pay 10 ETH to create game." # 10 ETH
    assert (0 <= _secret_number) and (_secret_number <= 100)
    self.game_index[self.curr_id].game_owner = msg.sender
    self.game_index[self.curr_id].game_balance = self.game_index[self.curr_id].game_balance + msg.value
    self.game_index[self.curr_id].secret_number = _secret_number
    self.game_index[self.curr_id].guess_count = 0
    self.game_index[self.curr_id].is_active = True
    self.curr_id = self.curr_id + 1
    return self.curr_id - 1

@external
@view
def get_game_balance(_game_id: uint256) -> uint256:
    return self.game_index[_game_id].game_balance

@external
@view
def get_game_guesses(_game_id: uint256) -> uint256:
    return self.game_index[_game_id].guess_count

@external
@view
def is_game_active(_game_id: uint256) -> bool:
    return self.game_index[_game_id].is_active

@external
@payable
def play_game(_game_id: uint256, _guess_number: uint256)->bool:
    assert msg.value == 10**18, "Pay 1 ETH to play this" # 1 ETH
    assert msg.sender != self.game_index[_game_id].game_owner, "Game owner can't play this game dude!"
    assert self.game_index[_game_id].is_active == True
    self.game_index[_game_id].game_balance = self.game_index[_game_id].game_balance + msg.value
    self.game_index[_game_id].guess_count = self.game_index[_game_id].guess_count + 1
    if _guess_number == self.game_index[_game_id].secret_number:
        send(msg.sender, (self.game_index[_game_id].game_balance * 99)/100)
        send(self.contract_owner, (self.game_index[_game_id].game_balance)/100)       
        self.game_index[_game_id].game_balance = 0
        self.game_index[_game_id].is_active = False
    else:
        if self.game_index[_game_id].guess_count == 10:
            send(self.game_index[_game_id].game_owner, (self.game_index[_game_id].game_balance * 99)/100)
            send(self.contract_owner, (self.game_index[_game_id].game_balance)/100)       
            self.game_index[_game_id].game_balance = 0
            self.game_index[_game_id].is_active = False
            
    return True
```

Unit test

```py
import pytest
from brownie import Wei, accounts, Guess_number201

@pytest.fixture
def guess_number():
    guess_number = Guess_number201.deploy({'from': accounts[0]})
    guess_number.create_game(9, {'from': accounts[1], 'value': "10 ether"})
    return guess_number

def test_wrong_guess(guess_number):
    pre_game_balance = guess_number.get_game_balance(0)
    pre_player_balance = accounts[2].balance()
    pre_guess_count = guess_number.get_game_guesses(0)
    guess_number.play_game(0, 8, {'from': accounts[2], 'value': "1 ether"})
    assert guess_number.get_game_balance(0) == pre_game_balance + Wei('1 ether'), "The game balance is not correct"
    # import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
    assert accounts[2].balance() == pre_player_balance - Wei('1 ether'), "The player balance is incorrect"
    assert guess_number.get_game_guesses(0) == pre_guess_count + 1
    assert guess_number.is_game_active(0) == True


def test_right_guess(guess_number):
    pre_game_bal2]ance = guess_number.get_game_balance(0)
    pre_player_balance = accounts[2].balance()
    pre_contract_owner_balance = accounts[0].balance()
    guess_number.play_game(0, 9, {'from': accounts[2], 'value': '1 ether'})
    assert guess_number.get_game_balance(0) == 0, "Balance of the game is not reset"
    assert accounts[0].balance() == pre_contract_owner_balance + (pre_game_balance + Wei('1 ether')) / 100, 'The commission is incorrect'
    # import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
    assert accounts[2].balance() == (pre_player_balance - Wei('1 ether')) + (pre_game_balance + Wei('1 ether')) * 99 / 100
    assert guess_number.is_game_active(0) == False, "Game status is not correct"
```

The `accounts[2]`(aka player) assert is failed for both case

```bash
============================================================= test session starts =============================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.9.1, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.10.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /Users/sarit/study/try_brownie/Vyper-03
plugins: eth-brownie-1.17.1, web3-5.24.0, hypothesis-6.24.0, xdist-1.34.0, forked-1.3.0
collected 2 items

tests/guess_number_test.py FF                                                                                                           [100%]

================================================================== FAILURES ===================================================================
______________________________________________________________ test_wrong_guess _______________________________________________________________

guess_number = <Guess_number201 Contract '0x63360A39ad3103eFFA89175706EC24F6e0671d1e'>

    def test_wrong_guess(guess_number):
        pre_game_balance = guess_number.get_game_balance(0)
        pre_player_balance = accounts[2].balance()
        pre_guess_count = guess_number.get_game_guesses(0)
        guess_number.play_game(0, 8, {'from': accounts[2], 'value': "1 ether"})
        assert guess_number.get_game_balance(0) == pre_game_balance + Wei('1 ether'), "The game balance is not correct"
        # import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
>       assert accounts[2].balance() == pre_player_balance - Wei('1 ether'), "The player balance is incorrect"
E       AssertionError: The player balance is incorrect
E       assert 122660026380000000000 == (123661068100000000000 - 1000000000000000000)
E        +  where 122660026380000000000 = <bound method PublicKeyAccount.balance of <Account '0xC17e55CC9168fD95359E4A17399E0Df70703BbA5'>>()
E        +    where <bound method PublicKeyAccount.balance of <Account '0xC17e55CC9168fD95359E4A17399E0Df70703BbA5'>> = <Account '0xC17e55CC9168fD95359E4A17399E0Df70703BbA5'>.balance
E        +  and   1000000000000000000 = Wei('1 ether')

tests/guess_number_test.py:17: AssertionError
______________________________________________________________ test_right_guess _______________________________________________________________

guess_number = <Guess_number201 Contract '0xe67EC05024c8E9aA4558c838a7F0A7D94289f4AC'>

    def test_right_guess(guess_number):
        pre_game_balance = guess_number.get_game_balance(0)
        pre_player_balance = accounts[2].balance()
        pre_contract_owner_balance = accounts[0].balance()
        guess_number.play_game(0, 9, {'from': accounts[2], 'value': '1 ether'})
        assert guess_number.get_game_balance(0) == 0, "Balance of the game is not reset"
        assert accounts[0].balance() == pre_contract_owner_balance + (pre_game_balance + Wei('1 ether')) / 100, 'The commission is incorrect'
        # import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
>       assert accounts[2].balance() == (pre_player_balance - Wei('1 ether')) + (pre_game_balance + Wei('1 ether')) * 99 / 100
E       AssertionError: assert 132549132520000000000 == ((122660026380000000000 - 1000000000000000000) + (((10000000000000000000 + 1000000000000000000) * 99) / 100))
E        +  where 132549132520000000000 = <bound method PublicKeyAccount.balance of <Account '0xC17e55CC9168fD95359E4A17399E0Df70703BbA5'>>()
E        +    where <bound method PublicKeyAccount.balance of <Account '0xC17e55CC9168fD95359E4A17399E0Df70703BbA5'>> = <Account '0xC17e55CC9168fD95359E4A17399E0Df70703BbA5'>.balance
E        +  and   1000000000000000000 = Wei('1 ether')
E        +  and   1000000000000000000 = Wei('1 ether')

tests/guess_number_test.py:30: AssertionError
=========================================================== short test summary info ===========================================================
FAILED tests/guess_number_test.py::test_wrong_guess - AssertionError: The player balance is incorrect
FAILED tests/guess_number_test.py::test_right_guess - AssertionError: assert 132549132520000000000 == ((122660026380000000000 - 100000000000...
============================================================== 2 failed in 2.05s =============================================================
```

Question:
How to do correct assert?